# elementary calculus inquiry

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Show that under the transformation $x = \rho\cos\phi$, $y = \rho\sin\phi$, the equation 
$$ \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial y^2} = 0$$ becomes
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \rho^2} = \frac{1}{\rho}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \rho} - \frac{1}{\rho^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial \phi^2} = 0$$

$u$ is function of $x$ and $y$

Comment: What is $\,u\,$?!

Comment: I don't see $v$ anywhere...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\del}[2]{\frac{\partial #1}{\partial #2}}$
Assuming $u$ is a smooth (or at the very least continuously second differentiable) function, you can use the chain rule. You know that $$\del{u}{x}=\del{\rho}{x}\del{u}{\rho} + \del{\phi}{x}\del{u}{\phi}$$
and similarily for $y$. You can iterate the relation to derive higher order derivatives and combine your results to get your identity.